# How to return back to home slide from another slide after hyperlink in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I am using Powerpoint 2007 and I have set up hyperlink from slide A to slide B in the same document. In the slide show, the hyperlink is working perfectly.

But after slide B, **how can I return back to slide A** itself?

My slide structure is as follows :

```
Slide A -> Link 1 to Slide B (after viewing slide B, should return back to Slide A)
           Link 2 to Slide C
           Link 3 to Slide D
```

How can I do this? When I set hyperlink, there is a option like SHOW AND RETURN, but it's disabled by default. How to enable it?

Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Link to Last Viewed Slide (or words to that effect).

That will always return you to the slide viewed immediately before the current slide.

Comment: Sorry.I could not understand.How to apply that link from one slide to another slide?

Comment: Add a hyperlink as you normally would, choose Place In This Document, then choose Previous Slide

Comment: For me, that takes me to the Previous slide, not to the Last viewed slide. With the notation of the OP, it does not take me to slide A, but to slide B-1.

Comment: @EscalinNancy there is an option for last viewed slide when you select 'Insert Action'

Answer (score 1):

Mark hyperlink, then 
Home -> Drawing -> Action Settings and there will be settings Last slide viewed